# mysql ON DELETE CASCADE

Tags: mysql

*network table*

```
"CREATE TABLE network("
 . "n_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,"
 . "nname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,"
 . "ndate DATE NOT NULL"
 . ");";
```

*locality table*

```
"CREATE TABLE locality("
 ."l_id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,"
 ."lname varchar(50) NOT NULL,"
 ."ldate varchar(50) NOT NULL,"
 ."n_id int NOT NULL,"
 . "CONSTRAINT locality_fk_1 FOREIGN KEY (n_id) REFERENCES network(n_id)ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE"
 . ");";
```

*Added from comments*:

It gives me an following error:

> Network not deletedCannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (accelore.locality, CONSTRAINT locality_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (n_id) REFERENCES network (n_id))

Comment: it gives me an following error                                                                            Network not deletedCannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`accelore`.`locality`, CONSTRAINT `locality_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`n_id`) REFERENCES `network` (`n_id`))

Answer (score 0):

You have added a foreign key constraint so it'll not get deleted directly,you have to drop the constraint first.
 `alter table locality drop constraint locality_ibfk_1` will drop the constraint and you can delete network OR
If you just want to delete data from both the table, use:

```
delete from network where n_id = n_id;
```

will delete all data in both the table without dropping any of the table. Or
If you use specific `n_id` it'll `delete` that particular data in both the tables.

Comment: alter table locality drop constraint locality_ibfk_1                                                where in the code i have to add this line ..plz send me the complete code

Comment: you can run this particular query anywhere before deleting the data,it'll not show error then.

Comment: Anyway it's the whole query. you are using mysql only so u just need to run this line before deleting data from tables.